# Usage of "flock" for a singular subject

Tags: meaning, verbs, word-usage

> Turned on by by his pheromones, she flocked to him.

Can we use *flock* when we have a singular subject?
What might be a better alternative to the verb?  Something like *ran*, but with a connotation of immediacy.

Comment: Are you quoting this from a published work, or some web reference, or your own writing?

Comment: General Reference: ***flock** - Congregate or mass in a flock or large group*. Obviously one person can't possibly do that in a literal sense, but can OP use it *figuratively?* Sure - witness [*she swarnmed all](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22she+swarmed+all%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) [over him]*, which has been "coined" many times by people who've never heard the usage before.

Answer (score 1):

Flocked sounds odd - a flock can flock, but not an individual.

Something simpler, like "rushed" or "hurried" or even "dashed" or "drew" would be more appropriate.

Comment: rushed would be my choice too.